# Как защититься от спама ботами на телеграм бота?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, ddos

Всем привет! Как защититься от флуда ботами в тг бота? Пробовал ограничить команду /start для новых пользователей, безуспешно, ботов довольно много. Отключил также логирование в бд, бот падает не намертво, но очень сильно лагает, пользоваться не возможно, может у кого есть идеи ? Бот на вебхуке, язык PHP

Comment: еси все, кто пишет вашему боту попадают в БД, выдайте каждому статус 0 - сообщения не обрабатываются статус 1 - наоборот.

Кадый новыйй пользователь добавляемый в БД будет иметь статус 0, но вы можете подтвердить его

А еще можно перед регистрацией в БД сделать проверку на isBot, если true? то статус 0 ии отказ в регистрации, если false то welcome baby)

Comment: я даже пытался вовсе отключить обработчик на /start, не помогает

Comment: Вы можете отключить доп. обработку /start но саму эту команду не отключить. Это встроенная функция бота

`$text = mb_strtolower($event["message"]["text"]);

if ($text == "/start") {
    // проверка бот или нет
}`